# How to register ObjectBox in GetIt?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-objectbox

How to properly register ObjectBox in GetIt? I have an error: The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ObjectBox Function()'.

```
final injector = GetIt.instance;

class DependencyInitializer {
  DependencyInitializer._();
  static void initDependencies() {
    injector
      //DataBase
      ..registerLazySingleton<ObjectBox>(ObjectBox);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a function/constructor that returns an instance. Passing 'ObjectBox' itself is just the type.

Try this:

```
  locator.registerLazySingletonAsync<ObjectBox>(() => ObjectBox.create());
```